# How to open image in dialogue box when click on the image?

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, android-imageview

In a Activity i want when user click on the image. the image will open in the dialogue box. with a big size.

```
private ImageView mImageView, FailedImg;
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mPinnedPostImg);
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);
            FailedImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ef_failed_image);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(list.getmImagePinnedPost())) {
                mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.failed_to_load_img);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {

                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
                        .load(list.getmImagePinnedPost())
                        .into(mImageView, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                FailedImg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.app_logo);
                                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: where is your click listner?

Comment: i did't put that. but it will be something like this. mImageView.setonclciklistener new view on clcik listener

Answer (score 0):

So you can create your custom dialog and open it when your image will get clicked:

```
  yourImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //in here open your dialog
            yourDialog diag = new yourDialog();
            diag.show();
        }
    });
```

Now, you can create your custom dialog like this :

```
public class yourDialog extends Dialog {
Context mContex;

public yourDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContex= context;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.invite_dialog);
    closeDialog();
}


private void closeDialog(){
    TextView exit = findViewById(R.id.xButton);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();//close your dialog
        }
    });
  }
}
```